# How to change UIWebView font by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, uiwebview

I am wondering how to change font by using JavaScript.

While this:

```
let fontName = "AmericanTypewriter-CondensedBold"

    if let infoString = config.textAboutApplication {
        infoView.loadHTMLString(NSString(format: "<div style='text-align:left;font-family:%@'>%@<div>", fontName, infoString) as String, baseURL: nil)
    }
```

produces proper outcome with formatted text, JavaScript version does not:

```
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView)
{
    let fontName = "AmericanTypewriter-CondensedBold"

    let jsString =  NSString(format: "document.getElementById('p').style.fontFamily = '%@'", fontName)
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(jsString as String)
}
```

The HTML text does have `p` tag and text inside, so I am doing something wrong regarding the JavaScript part probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was trying thing around, JavaScript is not my strongest thing, and this works

```
let fontName = "AmericanTypewriter-CondensedBold"

    let jsString =  NSString(format: "document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].style.fontFamily = '%@'", fontName)
    let js = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(jsString as String)
```

EDIT: I did custom implementation regarding this messy solution to be more swifty cool. :) https://github.com/Vanyaslav/Swiftyyjsformatter